# Sort multidimensional array in PHP using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example i have an array named `$slice` like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 23
        )

)
```

I want to sort array above so the output will be like this :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 8
                [3] => 12
                [4] => 20
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 7
                [2] => 9
                [3] => 10
                [4] => 23
            )

    )
```

Then i tried to use foreach and array_multisort, and when i use print_r the result is 1 for each col :

```
foreach ($slice1 as $col) {
    $slicesort[] = array_multisort($col);
}

output :
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: From the documentation: `array_multisort()` can be used to sort several arrays at once, or a multi-dimensional array by one or more dimensions. You're not sorting a multi-dimensional array; you're sorting elements of a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_multisort` sorts the array *in place*, it does not *return* the sorted array. You need to use it like this:

```
foreach ($slice1 as $col) {
    array_multisort($col);
    $slicesort[] = $col;
}
```

Having said this, `array_multisort` is somewhat overkill here, and I'm not sure that you really need to create a copy of the array. This will do just fine:

```
foreach ($slice1 as &$col) {
    sort($col);
}
```

This applies `sort` to each array within `$slice1` by reference, and thereby orders `$slice1` in place.

Comment: It's [useful to `unset($col);`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/3468/references/11993/pass-by-reference#t=201608251725013459463) after the `foreach` loop in your second solution so you don't inadvertently overwrite the array if you use another variable called `$col` later in the script.

Answer (score 1):

PHP `array_multisort`, as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), is for sorting multiple or multi-dimensional arrays, in your case you don't really need it.
In your case you just need `sort`, you can find the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

```php
$slicesort = array();
foreach ($slice1 as $col) {
    sort($col);
    $slicesort[] = $col;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$slice = array(
    array(12,4,8,2,10),
    array(9,7,1,10,13)
    );

foreach ($slice as &$arr) {
    sort($arr);
}

print_r($slice);
```

Answer (score 0):

array_multisort return a boolean value, true for success, false otherwise.

Change your code this way:

```
foreach ($slice1 as $col) {
    if (array_multisort($col)) {
        $slicesort[] = $col;
    }
}
```